# C# WPF Saving RadioSelect bool value to XML File (it's always false)

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-parsing, boolean

This is the XAML of the radio.  Nothing else is editing this.  Once this is set it is not changing.  But somehow no matter what it is setting the XML to "false".

Here is how I save the XML file (works just fine).
There are 3 radio buttons, as you can see, that I am trying to get set to false or true but they all just get saved as false.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="sx80" Content="Cisco SX80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="701,244,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="codecType" TabIndex="17" FontWeight="Normal" Height="25" Width="95" Padding="0,2"/>


class SaveXml
{
    public static void savedata(object obj, string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
       
        sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
        writer.Close();
    }

}
```

Here is the main class that tells it what information we are saving to the XML file.

```
public class information
{
    
 

  private string city;
    private string chairCount;
    private string stateSelect;
    private string HostNameIPTyped;
    private string VTCmac;
    private string vtcUser;
    private string vtcPass;
    private string VTCserial;
    private string AssetTag;
    private string SIPURI;
    private string SystemName;
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string contactPhone;
    private string provisionerName;
    private string provisionerInitials;
    private string provisionDate;
    private bool sx80;
    private bool codecPlus;
    private bool codecPro;


    public string postcity
    {
        get { return city; }
        set { city = value; }
    }
    public string postchairCount
    {
        get { return chairCount; }
        set { chairCount = value; }
    }
    public string poststateSelect
    {
        get { return stateSelect; }
        set { stateSelect =  value; }
    }
    public string postHostNameIPTyped
    {
        get { return HostNameIPTyped; }
        set { HostNameIPTyped = value; }
    }
    public string postVTCmac
    {
        get { return VTCmac; }
        set { VTCmac = value; }
    }
    public string postvtcUser
    {
        get { return vtcUser; }
        set { vtcUser = value; }
    }
    public string postvtcPass
    {
        get { return vtcPass; }
        set { vtcPass = value; }
    }
     { e164 = value; }
    }
    public string postVTCserial
    {
        get { return VTCserial; }
        set { VTCserial = value; }
    }
    public string postAssetTag
    {
        get { return AssetTag; }
        set { AssetTag = value; }
    }
    public string postSIPURI
    {
        get { return SIPURI; }
        set { SIPURI = value; }
    }
    public string postSystemName
    {
        get { return SystemName; }
        set { SystemName = value; }
    }
    public string postfirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }
    public string postlastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }
    

    public string postcontactPhone
    {
        get { return contactPhone; }
        set { contactPhone = value; }
    }
    public string postprovisionerName
    {
        get { return provisionerName; }
        set { provisionerName = value; }
    }
    public string postprovisionerInitials
    {
        get { return provisionerInitials; }
        set { provisionerInitials = value; }
    }
    public string postprovisionDate
    {
        get { return provisionDate; }
        set { provisionDate = value; }
    }

    public bool postsx80
    {
        get { return sx80; }
        set { sx80 = value; }
    }

    public bool postcodecPlus
    {
        get { return codecPlus; }
        set { codecPlus = value; }
    }

    public bool postcodecPro
    {
        get { return codecPro; }
        set { codecPro = value; }
    }


}
```

Comment: Copying your code into a test project, I do not get this result. There must be something else in your code that is causing this which isn't shown here.

Comment: I don't know how that could be because the only other thing is that it's a radio button and either checked or not checked.  Nothing else is changing that field

Comment: You'll have to either post more of your code (like the full class definition, for example), or try to diagnose things yourself. Try to reproduce the problem in a new project by gradually adding in components from the existing project until you get the problem again.

Comment: I've updated it.  Nothing affects the radio buttons and I would think that the fast that it's at least posting "false" it's getting something from somewhere.

Comment: Also for the record, all string values work perfectly.

Comment: A couple things. (1) In the code you posted, you seem to have a random line `{ e164 = value; }` that isn't part of any property. (2) Is there some reason you don't use [auto properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) instead of writing all the getters and setters manually?

Comment: Aside from the above, are you sure the `postsx80` property is *actually* being saved as `false`? Have you checked the actual xml file (e.g. in Notepad)?

Comment: The random string was something I meant to take out to make it a little easier to read.  And... I don't know how to use auto properties.  Yes, it is actually being saved as false.  If it didn't find a value it would just show nothing. :-)   <postsx80>false</postsx80>

Comment: Can you make a seperate project with just the `Infromation` class and the XML-save code and see if you still get this problem? I don't see this happening on my end.

Comment: Also, here's the MSDN page on [auto properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties). This will save you lots of unnessesary boiler-plate code.

Comment: We definitely don't need to look at all the 20 poorly defined properties. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Bizhan I am going to try Keith's way later today, but he asked for more so I gave more.  No need to demean a novice :-)

Comment: Sorry if my comment was intrusive, reading the help articles regarding "asking a good question" is encouraged by everyone. removing clutter from your question only takes a few seconds, but it takes/saves lots and lots of time from all the readers combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't show any data binding on the `RadioButton` or how you've set your `DataContext`. But you said in the comments that the strings are working so I assume you've set the DataContext somewhere. If you can update your question to show how your Window/View is bound to the `information` object it will be easier to give you a more accurate solution. You also said the following in one of your comments:

> Yes, it is actually being saved as false. If it didn't find a value it would just show nothing. :-) <postsx80>false</postsx80>

The default value for a `bool` is actually `false`, so even if no value is retrieved from your RadioButton, your XML file will still show `false`.

Your RadioButton's would normally be bound like this, depending on how your DataContext is set. Notice the Binding in the `IsChecked` property. The `Mode=TwoWay` means that the UI can set the value of the property and not just read it:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="sx80" Content="Cisco SX80" IsChecked="{Binding Info.postsx80, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In the code behind of this Window I have created a public property called `Info` which contains an instance of your `information` class. The RadioButton above is bound the the `postsx80` property of this `information` instance so you would need to pass this instance to your `savedata` method like below.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public information Info { get; set; } = new information(); // The UI is bound to this instance

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this; // I've set the Window's DataContext to itself
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveXml.savedata(Info, "somefile.xml");
    }
}
```

You should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` which will notify the UI when a property's value has changed. For example your `information` class could look like this:

```
// You will need to add the following namespaces
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace YourAppsNamespace
{
    public class information : INotifyPropertyChanged // Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
    {
        private bool sx80;

        public bool postsx80
        {
            get { return sx80; }
            set {
                sx80 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(); // Notify the UI that this property's value has changed
            }
        }

        // This code raises the event to notify the UI which property has changed
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

    }

}
```

You would need to add `OnPropertyChanged()` to the setters of all of your properties.

You also mentioned in the comments that you don't know how to use auto properties. An auto property is basically a shorter way to write a property when there are no additional actions which need to be performed when getting or setting a value. For example, this:

```
private bool someBool;
public bool SomeBool
{
    get { return someBool; }
    set { someBool = value; }
}
```

Would just become:

```
public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
```

There is no need to create the private variable or define the body of the getter and setter. This is handled automatically for you. This is only suitable if you don't need to perform any additional actions in the getter or setter. So in my example above where we need to call `OnPropertyNotifyChanged()` in the setter, you wouldn't be able to use an auto property.

An additional tip is that you can simply type `prop` in Visual Studio and press Tab twice to insert an auto property without having to type it out yourself. You then simply change the data type, press Tab again to move to the name and change that. The same can be done for a full property like the ones you wrote by typing `propfull`.